# この記号「φ」はなんですか？ 機械学習の文脈ではどういう意味ですか？

Tags: 機械学習, 数学

この画像の(Xi)の左横の記号はなんでしょうか？
またどういう意味でしょうか？
[image: 数式]

Comment: 数学一般の話かと思いましたので、タグを tensorflow から数学に変更しました。tensorflow 特有の意味がある場合は、どなたか修正して下さい。

Comment: ファイの小文字かな？ https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Φ

Comment: φはギリシャ文字の一つΦの小文字です。ガウスカーネルという文字が見えるので、Φは写像関数だろうと思います。詳しい話は https://github.com/levelfour/machine-learning-2014/wiki を読んでください。

Comment: オフトピックを理由としたクローズに反対します: 確かに本家 Stack Overflow では機械学習の実装面に関する質問のみが[推奨されています](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info)が、理論的な側面については [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)、[CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)、[DS](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) に誘導がついています。過去に[メタで議論された](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1546/19110)ように「幅広く受け入れる」ならば、このような投稿もギリギリオントピックではないでしょうか。

Comment: `tensorflow`開発上の`機械学習`に関わる疑問だと思いますので再オープン票を投じます。
`tensorflow`開発上の疑問であることからタグをつけられたのかと思いますが、編集されて削除されてしまったがために開発上で発生した疑問である旨が分かりづらくなったのではないでしょうか？
よく分かりませんが`機械学習`は画像や第一版のタグから推測されてつけられたのだと思いますが、`tensorflow`よりこちらの方がタグとして適切なのでしょうか？

Comment: @Myaku 「機械学習」タグは私がつけました。「tensorflow」タグをつけるべきかどうかは分かりませんが、話題自体は tensorflow に限らず機械学習一般（というかSVM）のものだと思うので、「機械学習」タグはつけておいていいのではないかと思います。（「tensorflow」タグと対比するつもりはありませんでした 汗）

Comment: 私が編集したタイトルがミスリードぎみだったと思いますので修正しました。タグに関しては、コメントした通りです。質問者さんにおかれましては、引用元と、数式が出てきた文脈を示していただけるとよいと思います。

Comment: 控えめな主張として個人的には現状ではやはりオフトピックじゃないかと思います．「`x` ってなんですか，機械学習の文脈ではどういう意味ですか？」「A. 変数を表します」はオントピックなんでしょうか．（詳しい文脈があれば確かに状況は）違うかもしれないとは思います．）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「φ」はギリシャ文字[「ファイ」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A6)の小文字です。「φ」は環境によって、ご質問の画像にあるような一筆書きの字形か、丸に斜線を引いた字形のどちらかに見えていると思いますが、どちらも同じ文字を表しています。

リンクした Wikipedia の記事や[英語版 Wikipedia の記事](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi)にあるように、「φ」は数学や物理学の世界では様々な意味で使われています。

今回の場合、φ はある関数を表しています。おそらく SVM におけるカーネル関数で使う[動系基底関数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E5%B0%84%E5%9F%BA%E5%BA%95%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0)を φ と置いているのだと思います。普通の数学で適当な関数を f と書くのと同じ感覚です。この文脈ではよく φ と書くので、慣習的なものだと考えても良いと思います（実際は何かしら理由があるのかもしれませんが、裏付けがとれませんでした）。